# How to get incremental serial number in Angular table pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pagination

I am using Angular table pagination. I have a serial number that starts from 1 for each page, but I want continuous page numbers. How to get it?

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <table id="myData">
        <thead>
            <td>S.no</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Age</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr dir-paginate="data in details | itemsPerPage:3">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{data.name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.age}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/mLvLzzg7/4/

If I try:

```
<td>{{itemsPerPage * (currentPage - 1) + $index + 1}}</td>
```

It is returning `null`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula for calculating the index is correct, but you didn't initialize your variables properly:

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 3;
    $scope.currentPage  = 1;
    $scope.details = [{
        ...
    }];
}

<tr dir-paginate="data in details | itemsPerPage:itemsPerPage" current-page="currentPage">
    <!-- now you can use itemsPerPage and currentPage to calculate index value -->
    <td>{{($index + 1) + (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage}}</td>
</tr>
```

Also, your fiddle didn't include **dirPagination** directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

And I updated jQuery version to newer one in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLvLzzg7/7/) - now the app works fine.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much:-) its working fine :-) can you please tell me ,why we need no add this `current-page="currentPage"` and how `$scope.currentPage` is changing automatically when we click on pages?

Comment: @laz `current-page` is a directives attribute that works like a getter and setter - https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/blob/master/src/directives/pagination/dirPagination.js#L185. You can specify a property in your controller `$scope.currentPage` and use it to get and set the current page of pagination.